# How to include local menu based on page id?

Tags: functions, pages, templates

I am creating different pages, using templates.

For example: `page-blog.php`. For certain group of pages, I would like to include a local navigation.

If I use page.php I am able to include the local nav by checking the id:

```
  if(is_page(array(18,52,22,20))) {
   // code
  }
```

But once I use a template for the page this does not work anymore. Where I need to check the id, so I can display local nav?

It is not convenient to do it in the templates because the website has too many pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also check if you are on page template with [is_page_template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) function:

```
  if(is_page(array(18,52,22,20)) || is_page_template( 'blog.php' )) {
       //do your stuff
  }
```